# How to convert from JSONSchema6 to JSONSchema4

Tags: json, typescript, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

I have been using the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema and have the schemas for validations in `JSONSchema6`.I have read that `JSONSchema6` is backward compatible with `JSONSchema4`. Is there any utility code to convert `JSONSchema6` to `JSONSchema4`? I need this as AWS API Gateway supports only `JSONSchema4` (as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-models)

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult to do by hand, or write a program to do so, as the differences between the two versions are straightforward. They are itemized here: https://json-schema.org/specification.html (scroll down for the links to differences between 4 and 6 for the two specification documents).